# Confused on Horizontal Card

Tags: html, css

I've been really struggling making a horizontal card. I don't want to use flexbox, because I'm not very experienced with it. I want something to look like this:

[image: Card]

I've already tried making the card and I'm able to get it to look similar although it doesn't adjust correctly to the text inputted in it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you learn some basic CSS in order to do simple layouts. Anyway here's a simple draft:

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 650px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.leftbox,
.rightbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left
}

.leftbox {}

.rightbox {
  border: 2px dashed pink;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 146px;
}

.header {
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

.data>p {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.leftbox {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftbox">
  </div><div class="rightbox">
    <div class="header">CARAMEL MACCHIATO</div>
    <div class="data">
      <p>SIZE</p>
      <p>TOPPINGS</p>
      <p>DELIVEERY</p>
      <p>AMOUNT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```